# what is the purpose of views_get_view_result()

Tags: views

HI I am modifying drupal 6 site and I am totally new to drupal.I have the following code

```
foreach ($alerts as $a) 
{
$filters = bevforce_filter_job_results($a['value']['alert_query_array']);
$results = views_get_view_result('jobs', 'block_4', $filters['title_nodes'], $filters['company'], $filters['city'], $filters['state'], $filters['zip'], $filters['types'], $filters['categories'], $filters['industries'], $filters['beverages'], $filters['user']);
}
```

In above code I am not finding any definition for the function views_get_view_result().I think this function is in built.Can any one tell me what views_get_view_result() does if its in built function.

Comment: Are you looking for a more sophisticated answer than to _"Get the result of a view."_? That's the function definition according to [the docs](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.module/function/views_get_view_result/6), it really doesn't need any further explanation. Please could you remove the second unrelated question and put it in a separate post. It's one question per question around here :)

Comment: yes I have made a simple one question now..will you help me now?

Comment: Sure...the purpose of the function is to _"Get the result of a view"_ and it comes from the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views). The function docs are linked to above...did you need to know something else about it?

Comment: yes My actual problem is here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54593/why-filter-is-not-working-in-drupal-6

Comment: I don't understand...do you need an answer to this question or not? Or did those comments answer it?

Comment: yes I need the answer sir.I am not understanding is it built in function.

Comment: It's not built into Drupal core, no, it's part of the contributed [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) which probably >95% of Drupal sites will have installed

Comment: thanks a lot.can we edit its parameter? and how to do it?

Comment: I think your filters all need to go in a single array as the third parameter passed. Check [this post](http://drupal.org/node/342132#comment-3726226) for an example